# Assembly.Load won't Invoke entrypoint on decrypted byte[] (exe), but will if from raw exe in resource, same MD5, what is the error?

Tags: c#, encryption, resources, gzip, .net-assembly

This code works

```
[STAThread]
static void Main()
{
    Assembly psrJA = Assembly.Load(Properties.Resources.Original );
    psrJA.EntryPoint.Invoke(null, null);

}
```

But when simply encrypting or even compressing the same byte[] it just stalls the cpu and hangs or it exits, the MD5 of both of the final executed exe's are the same I did File.Write on the decrypted exe and tested them both, But for some reason it wont invoke on the decrypted what is wrong with it?

Example of process hang (Not working)

```
[STAThread]
static void Main()
{
    Assembly psrJA = Assembly.Load(DecompressGZip(Properties.Resources.GZippedFile));
    psrJA.EntryPoint.Invoke(null, null);
}

public static byte[] DecompressGZip(byte[] bytesToDecompress)
{
    using (GZipStream stream = new GZipStream(new MemoryStream(bytesToDecompress), CompressionMode.Decompress)) 
    {
        const int size = 4096;
        byte[] Buffer = new byte[size]; { }
        using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            int count;
            do
            {
                count = stream.Read(Buffer, 0, size);

                if (count > 0)
                {
                    memoryStream.Write(Buffer, 0, count);
                }

            } while (count > 0);

            return memoryStream.ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```